# Firebase - Is there a way to set up to see what states in the US my users are coming from?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I can't seem to find out which state my users are coming from. The only data I see is that they are in the U.S. is there a way to configure something in Firebase so that I can track which states my users are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamView to see where users coming from at the City-level at real-time on the map. However, if you would like the data, I think you can do it yourself by using Geo location and log a user property with the location data.